# What tool to retain and compare detailed previous ganglia data?

Tags: ganglia

The loss of resolution in Ganglia makes it difficult for my product team to compare periods of load and test performance changes. We have bursty periods, separated by days or weeks. **What tools are available for saving detailed (e.g. hour-level) data from one period, and comparing it with data from another period?**

I'm using ganglia 3.1.7. The [Overlay timeshifted data](http://ganglia.info/?p=543) feature (which I don't have) looks like almost what I want. It appears that it will only save the previous period (because that's how rrdtool works). I want to be able to save and compare arbitrary periods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using RRDTool for storage: If you can manually configure the RRA parameters, it should be possible to do the same as is possible with Cacti: [configure your RRAs not to consolidate data](http://docs.cacti.net/manual:087:8_rrdtool.03_big_rra). The basics of this are:

- step size to 1
- rows to keep in the RRD (time interval to keep / polling interval)
- timespan to display

Some [other explanations of RRAs in Ganglia](http://blog.vuksan.com/tag/ganglia-rrd-monitoring/) and how to change the database used are also around, including [resizing existing RRDs](http://jeff.ourexchange.net/2012/03/22/expanding-ganglia-rrd-files/).